# Including a GeoDjango Point in a model

Tags: python, postgresql, geojson, geodjango

I am working with GeoDjango for the first time and am having trouble adding a `PointField` to my model. Here is my model code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Crime(models.Model):
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    District =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Incident = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=150,default="")
    Location = models.PointField()
```

When I try to create a migration, I get the error:

> ValueError: Cannot use object with type float for a geometry lookup parameter.

When I try to create a crime object in the Python shell and save it I get the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError

I've been troubleshooting this for quite a while now. I put a debugger in the actual gis library code and found that right before the `ValueError` was thrown, it was trying to process the number `35.0` as a geometry object.

I'm wondering if this error either has something to do with needing to set defaults in Django or if something is possibly wrong with my database connection?

Answer (score 11):

It turns out than passing in a default as an array of lat + long , which normally works to create a Point was not a valid option for gis to process when interpreting the schema. Here is a good default for gis point fields should anyone need one.

Figured out this solution by reading through this **very** old conversation: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/599

```
Location = models.PointField(default='POINT(0.0 0.0)')
```

Comment: Your solution [does not work for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507033/how-to-access-a-geometry-point-field-in-postgis-database-from-django) - maybe you have an advice.

Comment: @JJD It was an error in the settings.py file. This answer still seems to work great!